# What's Quoyles first name?

Tags: character, the-shipping-news

In the film and book of 'The Shipping News' (E. Annie Proloux) the main character is constantly refered to as 'Quoyle'. However, this is his surname or family name.

At one point in the book (when he becomes the papers editor) he's refered to as 'R. G. Quoyle'.

So, any idea what the 'R.G.' stands for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's unknown**. Just like they remain a mystery in the book ([see here](http://books.google.com/books?id=MkluuskLTLoC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=%22quoyle's%20first%20name%20is%20never%20revealed%22&source=bl&ots=hYB0e9leSD&sig=B4B741EEvxYmGzeILrCOI7g_2xg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7Jp3VJm0BI-Q7Abu7YCACg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22quoyle's%20first%20name%20is%20never%20revealed%22&f=false)), Quoyle's first and middle name are never revealed in the movie either ([see here](http://books.google.com/books?id=R5I9PQQjluQC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=%22shipping%20news%22%20Quoyle%20%22first%20name%22&source=bl&ots=T8qeXllGCt&sig=6h3Hq0gVUAHvYOOe297oxvXXRAg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZJl3VNmaOqiv7Abp24CgAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22shipping%20news%22%20Quoyle%20%22first%20name%22&f=false)). Sorry. :(